# Problems loading XML file (url cannot load) while local

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I'm trying to have my flash application interpret an XML file.
My code looks like:

```
var questions:XML = new XML();
questions.ignoreWhite=true;
questions.load('questions.txt');

questions.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
    if(success){
        if(questions.status == 0){
            trace("yay");
        } else { 
            trace("Problem parsing XML.");
        } 
    } else{
        trace("Could not load XML");
    }
}
stop();
```

the output i get is:

```
Could not load XML
Error opening URL 'file:///C|/Users/Peter/Desktop/Flash/questions.txt'
```

Does anyone have any idea why i can't access this file? I've verified that the URL works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be sure the file with the name questions.txt is there(in the same folder of your fla) coz the error is due to no file available at that url.

Don't worry about the extension, it can load txt or xml file. What all you need to do is give the correct file name.

Comment: the file should be available at that url, it is in the same directory and the URL works for my browser or windows explorer.

Comment: This is all, I've created an empty project with just the above script in it. Both the .swf and the .txt are in the same directory.
It's a mystery to me.

edit: appears it does work on my webserver... I wonder wtf is wrong with my pc.

Comment: FYI, the path ever you will give for a local file is a relative path and the url you are given is from the directory where your fla is placed. You can change it by setting SourcePath in ActionScript3.0 settings